# How should I wrap my pictures to save file size and speed

Tags: performance, ms-word, format, filesize, word-wrap

I am storing over 10 000 images in a MS Word portofilo, and as you can imagine when moving a large group of them (since they are all HD), not only does Word become significantly slow with but when I finish I deal with a large file size.

I have wraped all my pictures as "In Front Of Text". However, it then came to me that some wrap formats probably use less space then others. I tried to see if changing the wrap would make a difference, with little luck so I was wondering if anyone knew the optimal Text/Image Wrap for performance and file size.

Thanks in advance, Mona.

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion (only)

I am assuming that you are creating a portfolio of your work.
But why are you using Word for that? Instead use a better software like InDesign or Publisher or Corel Draw, these softwares can handle pretty large files efficiently.

Comment: I'm simply interested in which wrap format is most effiecient.

Comment: @Monacraft I think Thorough Wrapping is the most efficient one!

Comment: @Monacraft Here is an article: http://blogs.office.com/2011/05/26/understanding-images-part-2-wrapping-styles/

Comment: THanks for the article (it was very helpful in understanding what each wrapping does) however it doesn't specify anything on file size/performance.